# C++ less verbose alternative to passing container.start() and container.end()

Tags: c++, boost, stl, iterator, range

I declare a `vector<Bla> blaVec` and write a function:

```
template<typename Iterator>
void doSomething(Iterator first, Iterator last) { ... }
```

Then I call this function on `blaVec` with:

```
doSomething(blaVec.begin(), blaVec.end());
```

However, I really would like something shorter like `doSomething(blaVec)` but without having to specify `vector` in function definition. Basically, is there a good standard way to specify just the first iterator or maybe a range of [begin,end] iterators as is done by [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/range/doc/html/index.html).

I'm an algorithms guy so I really don't want to get into overly generic complex solutions. Most of my life I wrote functions like this:

```
void doSomething(vector<int> & bla) { ... }
```

However, these days, I frequently write `doSomething` that operates on `list` and `deque` and `vector` so a slightly more generic solution was called for, which is why I went with iterators. But it just seems to be too verbose of a solution. What do you suggest?

1. doSomething(vector & bla) { ... }
2. doSomething(Iterator first, Iterator last) { ... }
3. doSomething(/* some range data structure */) { ... }

Comment: You mention Boost.Range, so... why not use that? It has all kinds of nifty features too, like delayed evaluation and such.

Comment: I wasn't sure how commonly used it is. I like to use techniques that a lot of programmers are using, because my focus is on the algorithms not the software design aspect. I don't like being on the cutting edge of software engineering. It sometimes results in a time sink.

Comment: Additional verbosity is minimal, but the flexibility of iterator range interface is far superior. Moreover, if you only need to traverse the full range, the `std::for_each` is exactly designed for that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you find that verbose, then you can wrap that with this:

```
template<typename Container>
void doSomething(Container &c) 
{
  doSomething(c.begin(), c.end()); //internally call the iterator version.
}
```

And use this function, instead of iterator version.

Also, you can use iterator version, when you don't want the function to operate on all elements in the container. For example,

```
doSomething(c.begin(), c.begin() + 5); //operate on first 5 elements
                                       //assuming c.begin()+5 makes sense
```

Comment: +1. See boost::range for the ultimate tool in this regard. Use boost::begin/boost::end to allow Container to be any type, including c-arrays and strings.

Comment: @Macke: `std::string` has `begin` and `end` member functions.

Comment: @Xeo: I was referring to c-strings (const char*). Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: c++0x is not tagged. Otherwise, we could use doSomething( begin(c), end(c)); It works even for c-strings.

Answer (score -1):

Prefer the second one, as it is lot more flexible.

I don't feel it is verbose, but if you really insist, you might want to define a macro for it, eg:

```
#define FULLITER(a) a.begin(), a.end()
```

(just make sure `a` is a simple expression so it's not executed twice.)